# how to get logs into logstash server without using filebeats

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have logstash installed in a server which will process logs and publish to elastic search. But, is it possible for logstash to pull logs from remote servers (linux) without installing filebeats in those servers. 
Or if filebeats can be installed in the same server as logstash and can it fetch the logs? Please help me if there is any other option as well.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If both the servers are on same network ,logs can be sent from source server to logstash server on tcp/udp port or as syslog

Answer (score 0):

Neither Logstash nor Filebeat can pull/fetch log files from remote servers, you need to have some tool installed in the remote servers that will ship the logs elsewhere.

Logstash can consume logs from message queue systems like `kafka`, `redis` or `rabbitmq`, for example, but you need that your remote servers send the logs to those systems anyway, so you would need a log shipper on your remote servers.